# Programmatically Embed Resource in .NET Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, embedded-resource

I am trying to produce generic .NET executables that can be customized by changing the embedded resources. Ideally, I would like to be able to do this with a compiled executable, but it would also be acceptable to use some sort of intermediate representation. The key is that I need to be able to do this with a program, not manually.

Consider a C# program that looks something like this:

```cs
namespace MyProgram {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyProgram.Resources.foo"))
            {
                // ignore stream == null
                DoStuff(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will work as expected when some resource is embedded and named "foo". However, what I am trying to accomplish is building the program without the resource embedded, and then 'post-processing' the program to embed the resource. In fact, it would be even better if it's possible to both embed a new resource with an arbitrary name and add it to the resource manifest, so that at runtime the program can read the embedded resources and act on them.

Is there a way to programmatically embed new resources into a compiled .NET executable?

Comment: I'm betting the easiest way would be to modify the csproj file on-the-fly and use the compiler.

Comment: If I edit the csproj to include resources, will that automatically add them to the resource manifest, so that they can be enumerated at runtime? That's not a bad solution, if so...

Comment: It is not impossible, but recommended install locations and anti-malware being anti will give you a headache that nobody needs.  It just quickly stops making sense to distinguish a file that has an embedded resource that has to be created at runtime from the plain resource trivially been stored in a file.  Use System.CodeDom if you want to do this anyway.

Comment: Does it really need to be embedded?  We use server scripts to build and code-sign self-extracting archives that include an application plus dynamically customized additional files.  For PHP we use OSSLSignCode, for Tomcat we use some Java code-signing package (I don't know which one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you have a project called `Resources.csproj`.

You could copy resources into a specific directory (e.g. Content).

```
Project directory structure
----------------------------
Properties
  AssemblyInfo.cs
Content
  Item1.png
  Item2.png
```

You could then dynamically update your csproj file using `XDocument` or similar to include your content as embedded resources.

```
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Content\Item1.png" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Content\Item2.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

You could then compile the project however you like.

```
msbuild Resources.sln
```

Your resources should then be available in the output assembly. The advantage is that this approach avoids the overhead of dealing with `CodeDom`.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid invoking a compiler to build the customized executable, but otherwise this is a great solution. Thank you!